# How to get all category with their sum of products using their attribute in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get all category with sum of their products using status. If some of category have no product then show 0.
My category table is

```
------------------------
id     |  category     |
------------------------
1      | Apple         |
2      | Samsung       |
```

My product Table is

```
----------------------------------------
id     |Name     |category_id|is_half
----------------------------------------
1      |iphone 4s|1          |1
2      |iphone 5s|1          |0
3      |iphone 6 |1          |1
```

I want to get if product `is_half = 1` then sum using 0.5 else 1 .The result is

```
--------------------------------
id     |  category     |total
--------------------------------
1      | Apple         |2
2      | Samsung       |0
```

I try with this query, but bad luck

```
select c.id, c.name, sum(case when p.is_half then 0.5 else 1 end) as total
from category c left join products p
on p.category_id = c.id
group by c.id
```

Comment: What is your current output?  Your query looks right to me.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen result shows samsung also 2,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, it sums `1` even if there is no products. Add another `WHEN` to avoid that.

```
SELECT 
    c.id, 
    c.category, 
    SUM(
      CASE WHEN p.id IS NULL THEN 0 
           WHEN p.is_half THEN 0.5 ELSE 1 END
    ) 
    AS total 
FROM 
    category c 
    LEFT JOIN 
      products p 
      ON 
      p.category_id = c.id GROUP BY c.id
```

Also, you selected `c.name`, which is not valid field name. I changed it to `c.category`.

**OUTPUT**

```
--------------------------------
id     |  category     |total
--------------------------------
1      | Apple         |2
2      | Samsung       |0
```

See <kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2e68f/7)</kbd>